# How to save output from grub-md5-crypt to a file ?

Tags: security, password, encryption, grub, boot-loader

I am using Cent OS 6.5 and I want to save the generated output and md5 hash from `grub-md5-crypt` command to a file. 
The `grub-md5-crypt` command asks us to set a password. I want the password(which I have generated using a password generator) to be read from another file.

P.S. No mouse support and don't want to install gpm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grub-md5-crypt | tee -a file.txt` works fine.